# Removing duplicates using datetime and a numeric column

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to get each person First Transaction(the first transaction cannot be NA unless that person has not made any transaction). I can only get the earliest date, but that's not what I want. How can I get the desired output?

Current DataFrame

```
  Name                Date Transaction
1 John 2020/09/27 10:25:00         100
2 John 2020/09/27 11:30:00          NA
3 John 2020/09/27 12:30:00         250
4 Adam 2020/07/21 14:00:00          NA
5 Adam 2020/07/21 14:25:00         400
6 Adam 2020/07/21 14:45:00         200
5  Tom 2020/07/21 11:00:00          NA
6  Tom 2020/07/21 14:30:00          NA
6  Tom 2020/07/21 14:30:00          NA
```

Desired Output

```
  Name                Date Transaction
1 John 2020/09/27 10:25:00         100
2 Adam 2020/07/21 14:25:00         400
3  Tom 2020/07/21 11:00:00          NA
```

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("Adam", "John", "Tom"), class = "factor"), 
    Date = structure(c(6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("2020/07/21 11:00:00", 
    "2020/07/21 14:00:00", "2020/07/21 14:25:00", "2020/07/21 14:30:00", 
    "2020/07/21 14:45:00", "2020/09/27 10:25:00", "2020/09/27 11:30:00", 
    "2020/09/27 12:30:00"), class = "factor"), FirstTransaction = c(100, 
    NA, 250, NA, 400, 200, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Share your code, and share your data as `dput(mydata)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following with `dplyr` :

`arrange` the data by `Name` and `Date` and if all the `Transaction` values is `NA` return the 1st row or return the 1st non-NA row for each `Name`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::ymd_hms(Date)) %>%
  arrange(Name, Date) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  slice(if(all(is.na(Transaction))) 1L else which(!is.na(Transaction))[1])
  

#  Name  Date                Transaction
#  <chr> <dttm>                    <int>
#1 Adam  2020-07-21 14:25:00         400
#2 John  2020-09-27 10:25:00         100
#3 Tom   2020-07-21 11:00:00          NA
```

A shorter non-complex way suggested by @Paul would be :

```
df %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::ymd_hms(Date)) %>%
  arrange(Name, is.na(Transaction), Date) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  slice(1L)
```

Comment: If you change the sorting to `arrange(is.na(Transaction), Date)`, you can just use `slice(1)`.

Comment: Thank you, Ronak Shah and Paul, for the answer! Initially, the code was able to work. But somehow it is only showing the earliest date but not the first transaction at the moment. Initially, I thought the problem was with the data type. Name and Transaction was a factor and double, respectively. I tried changing it, but I was not able to get the desired outcome. I will be putting the dput in the question above. I hope you will be able to help me out

Comment: This still gives the desired output that you have shown in the post if you change  `Transaction` to `FirstTransaction`. Maybe we need a different example where the actual issue is.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that....Thank you again Ronak Shah and Paul for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Name) %>% 
summarise(Date = case_when(all(is.na(Transaction)) ~ Date[1], TRUE ~ Date[!is.na(Transaction)][1]),
Transaction = case_when(all(is.na(Transaction)) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ Transaction[!is.na(Transaction)][1]))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Name  Date                Transaction
  <chr> <dttm>                    <dbl>
1 Adam  2020-07-21 14:25:00         400
2 John  2020-09-27 10:25:00         100
3 Tom   2020-07-21 11:00:00          NA
```